# debug blazor wasm when using custom domain

Tags: debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly, iis-express

Im building some Blazor wasm project

and to access OIDC i had to make my dev iis expres to run under https:/xxx.localhost
and OIDC is veryfying this callback url so it mus be like that

so i had to add to my hosts `xxx.localhost 127.0.0.1`
and then edit
`applicationhost.config` and add

```
 <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:xxx.localhost" />
```

then

```
 netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=certhash.. appid={appid...}
```

and it is wotking - now i can run it on `xxx.localhost` but i canot debug.

i see breakpoints not hit like like this
[image]

what shoud i do to be able to debug like this also? did i do something wrong ? please advise.
best regards !

Comment: Have you update launchsettings.json if not look at   "inspectUri":  and match the urls and ports

Comment: in client or server project? does this what is in client even matter at all??

Comment: i checked both options. as son as i leafe localhost and change itto xx.locakhost then debug of client breaks;/

Comment: makes sense as the origin does not match, you may need to gen a local HTTPS cert with the name as your 443 binding will need updating

Comment: it is not that - i generated New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "xx.localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"  CN=xx.localhost. did netsh http del and then add with new. now i can access https://xx.localhost and cert is valid and still no debug;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future readers
solution was pretty simple
issue was with my corp network and PROXY

for xx.localhost it was going thru proxy not directly !!!

shame on me
regrds.